How to properly migrate to Sass @use in nuxt2?
We want to reuse some of our mixins and variables in both current Nuxt2 and the new Next.js projects.
Next.js highlighted the @import in Sass is getting deprecated, so to overcome this, we have rewritten the styles library with @use.
However I can't make it work in Nuxt as expected. I have tried multiple configuration of nuxt.config, but the latest problem that I can't overcome is that inside Vue files seems the Sass modules are not visible.
Is there a way to make them globally visible?
"sass": "~1.32.13",
"sass-loader": "^10.5.2"

nuxt.config portion related to styles:
    styleResources: {
      scss: [
        ... // using @/assets/v4/style/index.scss here gives me other errors
      ]
    },
    css: [
      '@/assets/v4/style/index.scss',
         ...
    ],

/assets/v4/style/index.scss:
@use "./variables.scss";
@use "./enums.scss";
@use "./spacing.scss";
@use "./fonts.scss";
@use "./mixins.scss";
@use "./typography.scss";

Error:
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):                               friendly-errors 4:55:05 PM
SassError: There is no module with the namespace "variables".
    ╷
418 │     padding-bottom: variables.$space-16;
    │                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  pages/store/index.vue 418:21  root stylesheet

